# Is there something wrong with my code to give me the wrong output?

Tags: c

so i have to write a program that gives me the days of the month entered by a user. it compiles and runs but the only output it gives me is 30 days. im using a driver.c file, days.c file and days.h file.

iʻve tried changing my variables and rearranging the order of my if else statements but nothings changed

here's the code in my driver.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "days.h"

int main()
{
        int month;
        int year;

        //user enters month
        printf("Enter a month (1-12): ");
        scanf("%d", &month);

        while(month != 0)
        {
               if(days_in_month(month, year) == 31)
               {
                    printf("This month has 31 days\n");
               }
               else
               {
                    printf("This month has 30 days\n");
               }
               if(days_in_month(month, year) == 28)
               {
                    printf("This month has 28 days");
               }

               printf("Enter a month (1-12): ");
               scanf("%d", &month);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

and here's the code in the days.c file

```
int days_in_month(int month, int year)
{
        //variables
        int month_given;
        int num_days;

        if (month_given== 1 || month_given== 3 || month_given== 5    || month_given== 7 || month_given== 8 || month_given== 10 || month_given== 12)
        {
                num_days== 31;
        }
        else if(month_given== 4 || month_given== 6 || month_given== 9 || month_given== 11)
        {
                num_days== 30;
        }
        else(month_given== 2);
        {
                num_days== 28;
        }
}
```

its supposed to give out 30 days, 31 days or 28 days depending on what month the user entered

Comment: Your function days_in_months isn't returning anything, that's why.

Comment: Turn on all your compiler warnings - and make sure you fix all the warnings.

Comment: You are comparing month with an int which not initialized and you do not return the result of your function. Just change month_given by month in your function and as Lucas said, return num_days.

Comment: It's even worse than that. Also remove the double == from the affectation of num_days. You are doing an inequality! not an affectation!

Comment: This is in urgent need of a look-up table. Additionally February has either 29 or 28 days depending on the year. You also fail to initialize `year` among numerous other problems others have pointed out.

Comment: Another tip: `printf("This month has %d days\n", days_in_month(month, year))`. Let the code do the work for you, don't copy-paste your way to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the output gives you 30 days is because...

The function "days_in_month" is supposed to return an integer but you are not returning one explicitly.The function, thus, defaults to returning an integer implicitly but it is not what is expected, this causes the `if(days_in_month(month, year) == 31)` condition to fail each time and the code prints the text in the `else` block.

Apart from this, there are other inaccuracies in the code:

1. The "month" parameter passed to the "days_in_month" function
   is not utilized anywhere within the function.
2. In the "days_in_month" function, you are checking for equality
   for `num_days`(ex: `num_days== 31`). This should instead be
   `num_days = 31`.
3. In the "days_in_month" function the `else(month_given== 2);`
   is not correct."else" is the default case and should be followed by
   a statement. It does not check conditions.
4. The `while` statement should also check for input greater than 12.
   Like so `while(month != 0 && month < 13)`
5. Lastly, there is a logical flaw in the placement of the "else"
       clause in the "main" function.Please note that "else" handles the
       "none of the above" condition.By placing the "else" in between two
       "if"s, if the first "if" fails, the "else" is guaranteed to execute even before the second "if" is tested.

Implementing the corrections would result is a working code(listed below)....but there is scope for improvement.

1.The variable "year" is declared but not utilized anywhere.You should 
   collect input for this variable and implement a condition to display 
   the correct days for February depending on whether the year is a
   leap year or not.Preferably in "main".

2.You could call "days_in_month" just once and check the returned value
   with the conditions.

```
int main()
{
    int month;
    int year;

    //user enters month
    printf("Enter a month (1-12): ");
    scanf("%d", &month);

    while(month != 0 && month < 13) //input between 1 and 12
    {
           if(days_in_month(month, year) == 31)
           {
                printf("This month has 31 days\n");
           }

           else if(days_in_month(month, year) == 28)
           {
                printf("This month has 28 days\n");
           }

           else                                    //tagging else at the end
           {
                printf("This month has 30 days\n"); 
           }


           printf("Enter a month (1-12): ");
           scanf("%d", &month);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

days.c

```
int days_in_month(int month, int year)
{
    //variables
    int month_given;
    int num_days;
    month_given = month; //assigning month to month_given

    if (month_given== 1 || month_given== 3 || month_given== 5    || month_given== 7 || month_given== 8 || month_given== 10 || month_given== 12)
    {
            num_days= 31;
    }
    else if(month_given== 4 || month_given== 6 || month_given== 9 || month_given== 11)
    {
            num_days= 30;
    }
    else //removed the conditional check (month_given== 2);
    {
            num_days= 28;
    }
    return num_days; //returning num_days
}
```